# How to fade in/out between songs with a WPF C# mediaelement

Tags: c#, wpf, fade, mediaelement

I am writing a media player and I'm using WPF in C#.

My problem is that I have no idea of how to create a fade in/ fade out function (using the media element), meaning that the last 7 seconds of the playing song will start to fade out and at the same time the first 7 seconds of the next song will start to play.

Has anyone done this? If so, then can someone please help me?
Thank you.

Comment: Could we see your code?

Answer (score 2):

you can animate the UIElement.Opacity property to achieve video fading...

Here is a link for fading the video
http://www.darinhiggins.com/fading-two-video-windows-in-wpf/

Similarly for fading the audio, you could animate the MediaElement.Volume property.

Answer (score 2):

You could put a trigger on [MediaElement.Position](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.position%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that starts a DoubleAnimation on [MediaElement.Volume](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.volume%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) when within seven seconds of the end ([MediaElement.NaturalDuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.naturalduration%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

Answer (score 1):

```
myMediaElement.Play();
myMediaElement.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, new DoubleAnimation(myMediaElement.Opacity, 0, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)));
myMediaElement.BeginAnimation(MediaElement.VolumeProperty, new DoubleAnimation(myMediaElement.Volume, 0, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(11)));

myMediaElement1.Play();
myMediaElement1.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, new DoubleAnimation(myMediaElement1.Opacity, 1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)));
myMediaElement1.BeginAnimation(MediaElement.VolumeProperty, new DoubleAnimation(myMediaElement1.Volume, 1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(11)));
```

Hope this helps.. Just create two MediaElements, works for volume, and visual.