# How do I fade out the audio of a .wav file using SoundPlayer instead of stopping it immediately?

Tags: c#, winforms, soundplayer

I'm trying to stop sound as soon as I release the button, but what happens is that file is played fully.
I don't want to stop the sound abruptly as it happened with `sp.Stop()`.
Is there a way to do this?

```
private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(sender == mk)
    {
        if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            SoundPlayer sp = new SoundPlayer();

            sp.SoundLocation = (@"C:\my path\sound.wav");
            sp.Play();
        }
    }
}

private void button1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(sender == mk)
    {
        if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        { /*some code here (without sp.Stop())*/ }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that when you "stop" the sound you want it to fade out or something similar?

Comment: The answer is most likely threads :)

Comment: @test yep. doing a simple music composer and stopping like Stop() does sounds awful

Comment: I guess you could lower the volume progressively and once at 0% do a Stop.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault You won't have access to the volume via `SoundPlayer`. If OP was using WPF, then it would be possible with a `MediaElement`.

Comment: @test Oh, you're right, my bad. `SoundPlayer` indeed don't have any control on its own volume.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm interpreting your question as:

> How do I fade out the audio of a .wav file using `SoundPlayer` instead of stopping it immediately?

The short answer is that you can't do it with `SoundPlayer` alone. You'll need the use of a couple apis from the `winmm.dll` library.

If you are comfortable with WPF, then using a `MediaElement` with a `DoubleAnimation` on it's volume property is probably a better way to do this. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22500918/how-to-fade-in-out-between-songs-with-a-wpf-c-sharp-mediaelement) question for information on that.

However if you really want to use WinForms, the following is an implementation that should work.

**Notes about `Form1`:**

- Two buttons, named `startButton` and `stopButton`
- A timer named `timer1` that I use to fade out the sound

Here is the code to get this working:

```cs
using System;
using System.Media;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        [DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint = "waveOutGetVolume")]
        private static extern int WaveOutGetVolume(IntPtr hwo, out uint dwVolume);

        [DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint="waveOutSetVolume")]
        private static extern int WaveOutSetVolume(IntPtr hwo, uint dwVolume);

        private SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer();

        // a crude delta time field
        private float totalElapsedTime;

        // tweak this value to determine how quickly you want the fade to happen
        private const float Velocity = 0.001f;

        public Form1()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            // i was using 100 milliseconds as my "frame rate"
            this.timer1.Interval = 100;
            this.stopButton.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // sets the audio device volume to the max.
            // this is not the computer's volume so it won't
            // blast out your ear drums by doing this unless you
            // have the computer volume super high - which is not this
            // code's fault
            WaveOutSetVolume(IntPtr.Zero, uint.MaxValue);

            this.startButton.Enabled = false;
            this.stopButton.Enabled = true;

            this.totalElapsedTime = 0f;
            this.player.SoundLocation = @"Music File.wav";
            this.player.Load();
            this.player.Play();
        }

        private void stopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // being the stop
            this.timer1.Start();
            this.stopButton.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // amount to interpolate (value between 0 and 1 inclusive)
            float amount = Math.Min(1f, this.totalElapsedTime * Velocity);

            // the new channel volume after a lerp
            float lerped = Lerp(ushort.MaxValue, 0, amount);

            // each channel's volume is actually represented as a ushort
            ushort channelVolume = (ushort)lerped;

            // the new volume for all the channels
            uint volume = (uint)channelVolume | ((uint)channelVolume << 16);

            // sets the volume 
            WaveOutSetVolume(IntPtr.Zero, volume);

            // checks if the interpolation is finished
            if (amount >= 1f)
            {
                // stop the timer 
                this.timer1.Stop();

                // stop the player
                this.player.Stop();

                // stop is complete so let user start again
                this.startButton.Enabled = true;
            }

            // add the elapsed milliseconds (very crude delta time)
            this.totalElapsedTime += this.timer1.Interval;
        }

        public static float Lerp(float value1, float value2, float amount)
        {
            // does a linear interpolation
            return (value1 + ((value2 - value1) * amount));
        }

    }

}
```

Hopefully this should be pretty self-explanatory. I think most people will recognize this as a crude "game-loop-esqe" approach, but it seems to work well. Of note here is that to tweak the speed at which the fade happens is the `Velocity` constant.

The code is setup to fade out over 1 second. It's easy to figure that out by looking at the `timer1.Interval` and the `Velocity`. After 1000 milliseconds (10 timer ticks) then 1000 * 0.001 = 1 which causes the stop code to complete.

The only reason to change the `timer1.Interval` is to make more "fades" occur. Current setup does 10 volume fades before stopping.

Comment: Wow. Just wow. You rock! I managed to assign them to actual events, so now its working how i need it to work. Thanks a lot!